# How many distinct postitive integers satisfy the identity $x+y+z+w = 100$?

Tags: combinations

Let's say we have $4$ positive integers $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$ that satisfy the property：
$$x+ y+ z+ w = 100$$
How many possible distinct answers are there?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. To get help here you should get started and show us where you are stuck. Can you solve the problem if you try it with a number much smaller than $100? With fewer than four summands?

Comment: It seems like it should be a very similar problem to count ways of picking 3 different numbers a<b<c< 100. Then you could let w=100-c, z= c-b, y = b-a, and x = a.

Comment: @Robo300 It's way easier to just stars and bars here. The answer is just $$99\choose3$$

Comment: As you have not specified that the integers must be nonnegative, there are infinitely many solutions, no?

Comment: @XanderHenderson i originally answered that way. Then I reread the title.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Oi... this is why vital parts of the question should be *in the question*, and not the title alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write up a quick answer since this will be closed soon, but by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars), we first assign $4$ of the $100$ to each variable to ensure that they will be positive. So, we have $96$ indistinguishable objects to distribute in $4$ buckets, giving us $${96+4-1\choose4-1}={99\choose3}=\color{red}{156849}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct approach:

For each choice of $x$, we count the number of sums $y+z+w=97-x$.

For each choice of $x$ and $y$, we count the number of sums $z+w=98-x-y$.

For each choice of $x$, $y$ and $z$, there is only one such $w=99-x-y-z$.

$$\sum_{x=1}^{97}\sum_{y=1}^{98-x}\sum_{z=1}^{99-x-y} 1 = \sum_{x=1}^{97}\sum_{y=1}^{98-x}(99-x-y) = 156849$$

Comment: Hi Don, it's the same as yours. I think you just made a typo